# Animate PNG sprite (copy 2DRig) loaded at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop an application that scans a drawing and then adds it to a visualization. The part where I'm struggling is that the sprite has to have a predefined animation. So the animation needs to have the "skin" of the drawing.

My initial idea was to have a prefab of the sprite rigged in 2D (a PNG) with the animation preconfigured and then change the model sprite with the one loaded after the scan. It's not working. Then I imagined that maybe if I'm able to copy the 2D rig from the model to the loaded sprite I could achieve my goal but I haven't found a solution.

I have seen that it's possible so change parts of a sprite but I would like to change the whole sprite.

Is there a way to do what I explained?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.